# Proof of the general Hurewicz theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Here is the link to the book: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

In the proof of Theorem 4.37(p.372), there is a huge diagram and the picture below is a portion of it:

[image]

The definition of the groups $\pi_n'$ are explained in the last paragraph in p.370.

I can't see where the map $\partial '$ came from. It seems that it is induced by the map $\partial$. However, in order to $\partial$ passes to the quotient and induce $\partial'$, the image under $\partial$ of the kernel of the map $\pi_{n+1}(X,X^n \cup A) \to \pi_{n+1}'(X,X^n \cup A)$ must be contained in the kernel of the map $\pi_n(X^n\cup A,A)\to \pi_n'(X^n \cup A,A)$. I tried to verify this, but I found that this is highly nontrivial. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is because $\partial ([\gamma]\cdot [f])=\gamma\cdot\partial[f]$. I do not know where Hatcher proves this. It is Theorem 6.63 in the copy of Davis-Kirk's book which I have.

Comment: @Tyrone I see that $\partial ([\gamma][f])=[\gamma](\partial[f]) \in \pi_n(X)$ obviously holds when $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(A)$ and $[f] \in \pi_{n+1}(X,A)$. But the above situation is little bit different; we have to show that $\partial ([\gamma][f])=[\gamma](\partial[f]) \in \pi_n(X^n\cup A,A)$ when $[\gamma]\in \pi_1(X^n\cup A)$ and $[f]\in \pi_{n+1}(X,X^n \cup A)$ and if you compare p.341 and p.345 of Hatcher, you'll see that the action of $\pi_1(A)$ on absolute $\pi_n$ groups and that on relative $\pi_n$ groups are quite different.